# echo $variable in cron not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

Im having trouble printing the result of the following when run by a cron. I have a script name under /usr/local/bin/test

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

ARAW=`date +%y%m%d`

NAME=`hostname`

TODAY=`date '+%D %r'`

cd /directory/bar/foo/
VARR=$(ls -lrt /directory/bar/foo/ | tail -1 | awk {'print $8'} | ls -lrt `xargs` | grep something)

echo "Resolve2 Backup" > /home/user/result.txt

echo " " >> /home/user/result.txt

echo "$VARR" >> /home/user/result.txt

mail -s "Result $TODAY" email@email.com < /home/user/result.txt
```

I configured it in /etc/cron.d/test to run every 1am:

```
00 1 * * * root /usr/local/bin/test
```

When Im running it manually in command line

```
# /usr/local/bin/test
```

Im getting the complete value. But when I let cron do the work, it never display the part of `echo "$VARR" >> /home/user/result.txt`

Any ideas?

Comment: `VARR=$(ls -lrt /directory/bar/foo/ | tail -1 | awk {'print $8'} | ls -lrt `xargs` | grep something)` is a very untidy command, and you should avoid trying to parse the output of `ls`. What information are you trying to get?

Comment: Aside from anything else about that mess of a command `ls -ltr \`xargs\`` is *astonishingly* odd/bad (though clever I guess).

Comment: The criticism of the ls parsing is not just valid, it is quite likely your problem--ls is sensitive to a number of shell variables. You don't need the -l if all you want is the filename; ls will show only one file per line if its output is not a tty.  How does what you want differ from $(ls -lrt | tail -1 | grep something) anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
VARR=$(ls -lrt /directory/bar/foo/ | tail -1 | awk {'print $8'} | ls -lrt `xargs` | grep something)
```

`ls -ltr /path/to/dir` will *not* include the directory in the filename part of the output. Then, you call `ls` again with this output, and this will look in your **current directory**, not in `/path/to/dir`.

In cron, your current directory is likely to be `/`, and in your manual testing, I bet your current directory is `/path/to/dir`

Here's another approach to finding the newest file in a directory that emits the full path name:

```
stat -c '%Y %n' /path/to/dir/* | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d" " -f 2-
```

Requires GNU stat, check your man page for the correct invocation for your system.

---

I think your `VARR` invocation can be:

```
latest_dir=$(stat -c '%Y %n' /path/to/dir/* | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d" " -f 2-)
interesting_files=$(ls -ltr "$latest_dir"/*something*)
```

Then, no need for a temp file:

```
{
    echo "Resolve2 Backup"
    echo
    echo "$interesting_files"
} |
mail -s "Result $TODAY" email@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your tips and response. I solved my problem. The problem is the ouput of $8 and $9 in cron. I dont know what special field being read while it  is being run in cron. Im just a newbie in scripting so sorry for my bad script =)